# How do I create a schema to accept array of file objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, form-data

**formData array of files:**

```
const noteSubmitHandler = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
      formData.append('files[]', attachments[i]);
    }
    formData.append('title', title);

    await sendRequest(
      process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + '/notes/create',
      'POST',
      formData,
      { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token }
    );
    navigate(`/${auth.userId}/notes`);
  } catch (err) { }
};
```

**Input:**

```
<input
  type="file"
  accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
  multiple
  onChange={(e) => setAttachments(e.target.files)}
/>
```

If I `console.log(formData.getAll('files[]'));` I get an array of files as expected:

[image]

How do I set up the schema on the backend to accept the array? I've tried:

```
const noteSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  "files[]": [{ type: Object }],
});
```

and

```
const noteSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  files: [{ type: Object }],
});
```

but neither work.

Comment: Which database you are using? Mongodb? mysql?

Comment: @Mr Khan Using Moongodb

Comment: If you want to add the FIle strucutre received from the browser then thats not possible.  Its a browser object

Comment: What would I need to do to successfully pass a file object array to the backend?

Comment: Added a answer below

Comment: Please accept and vote if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant store the file object from Browser into Mongodb but you can extract the properties and store it as an array. Here's how to structure your `noteSchema`.

**noteSchema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  data: { type: Buffer, required: true },
  contentType: { type: String, required: true }
});

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  files: [fileSchema] // Embed the file data within the Note schema
});

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);

module.exports = Note;
```

In this File model, we store the file's name, binary data, and content type. You can adjust the fields in the fileSchema based on your requirements.

When you receive the files on the server, you should save each file as a separate document in the Note model. You can get files array by using Multer.

**Create Note file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const router = express.Router();
const Note = require('../models/note');

const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/notes/create', upload.array('files'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title } = req.body;
    const files = req.files;

    // Create a new Note instance with embedded file data
    const newNote = new Note({
      title,
      files: files.map(file => ({
        name: file.originalname,
        data: file.buffer,
        contentType: file.mimetype
      }))
    });

    // Save the Note instance to the database
    const savedNote = await newNote.save();

    res.status(201).json({ note: savedNote });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```